# Why output of Custom average filer's (3x3) is not same as average filter of opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have implemented an average filtering code in Python and received an output. And I also applied OpenCV's blur method on the same 2D array.

But the result of both filters are not the same (ideally they should be). Can you please tell me the reason?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

def averageFilter(im, size=3):
  imag = np.copy(im) # make copy of the image
  w = math.floor(size/2)

  for i in range(1, im.shape[0]):
    for j in range(1, im.shape[1]):
      block = im[ i-w : i+w+1, j-w : j+w+1] # 3x3 filter
      m = np.mean(block, dtype=np.float32)
      imag[i, j] = int( round(m))
  return imag


avg_img = averageFilter(img)

blur = cv2.blur(img,(3,3)) 




avg_img 
array([[ 15,  15,  15,  40,  90, 130, 130, 160, 160],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 122, 132, 133],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 122, 132, 133],
       [ 15,  42,  50,  48,  87, 117, 123, 133, 134],
       [ 15,  42,  50,  48,  87, 117, 123, 133, 134],
       [ 15,  42,  50,  48,  87, 117, 123, 133, 134],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 140, 150, 160],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 140, 150, 160]])

blur
array([[ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 104, 114,  89],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 122, 132, 124],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 122, 132, 124],
       [ 68,  42,  50,  48,  87, 117, 123, 133, 126],
       [ 68,  42,  50,  48,  87, 117, 123, 133, 126],
       [ 68,  42,  50,  48,  87, 117, 123, 133, 126],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 140, 150, 160],
       [ 15,  15,  23,  48,  87, 117, 140, 150, 160]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Possibly it has to do with boundary conditions. You are likely not doing what openCV is doing

Comment: Actually, I want to know what I am missing, which OpenCV method is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not touching the border pixels at all while opencv is also averaging the border pixels by padding the image to be large enough

The default behavior of opencv is to *reflect* your values over the borders and use the reflected values.

This matrix

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

is padded to

```
5 4 5 6 5
2 1 2 3 2
5 4 5 6 5
8 7 8 9 8
5 4 5 6 5
```

and the convolution is carried out.

You can take a look at `cv2.copyMakeBorder` for details and other options of the padding.